# Not able to create product in shopify

Tags: shopify, shopify-app, shopify-api, shopify-api-node

I started with these commands

```
shopify node create
shopify node serve
```

installed app by going to ngrok link

then I tried to create product with

```
shopify populate products
```

but I am getting this error

> Command not allowed with current login. Please check your login details with shopify whoami. You may need to request additional permissions for this action.

Answer (score 0):

As per the message within the error, this is caused by your API credentials, whether that be for the current staff account, or the Private App that has been used to generate the access tokens.

You will need to speak to the account owner of the Shopify store that you are accessing to get your privileges upgraded.